# Why reverseSeek not supported in tikv?

Tags: tidb, tikv

I'v seen that in tikv v2.0.9, ScanRequest have not support reverse param, also befor reverseSeek don't work, however in some time, I need reverseSeek, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

TiKV has two types of kv API(txn and raw), both of them can scan reversely,

- Txn KV: reverse kv_scan is available from v2.1.0-beta,
- Raw KV: reverse raw_scan is only available on master([30251412](https://github.com/tikv/tikv/commit/30251412e909acce59f0a829892453d92bd01922)). Because it is an experimental feature.

Please consider upgrade to TiKV v2.1-rc if you want reverse kv_scan.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I have try today for different version, found that from v2.1.* support reverseSeek, Howerver our current tikv is v2.0.0， so I used reverseSeek wrongly!